# How to set the default tab pagination to 2 spaces in gedit?

Tags: 14.04, gedit

I am using gedit in ubuntu 14.04 for developping web applications, and I 
use tabs a lot in my code instead of spaces.

Everytime I open gedit it sets the tab pagination to 8 spaces.

How do I set it to 2 by default ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `gedit` menu, go to **Edit -> Preferences**.
When the **gedit Preferences** window pops up, click on the **Editor** tab, and you will be able to change the Tab Width setting accordingly.